# Баг или "кэш" javascript'a?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Иногда бывает код изменил, сохранил через файлзилу на сервере, **но страница ведет себя так же, как ДО обновления кода**. CTRL+R и режим инкогнито не помогают.  Обычно ВРЕМЯ исправляет данные баги.

Comment: `jQuery(function($){})` aka document.ready делаете?

http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#itsabug

Comment: Закрывающая фигурная скобка (end функции) потерялась

Comment: да, но это тут явно ни при чем, у меня даже js внизу страницы))

Comment: Ну что сказать, "такого не бывает ?" Может, пример рабочий сделаете? http://plnkr.co/edit/ подходит для таких проблем

Comment: В данном случае оказалось, что код оказался в блоке .on('mousewheel'... Но КАК КОД ИНОГДА РАБОТАЛ, не понимаю))) Но данная проблема из ряда 'регулярных'. В консоли всегда отслеживаю возможные ошибки на скобки и т.п. (поставлю все-таки BracketHighlighter для sublime text'a)

Comment: а чего непонятного, повернули колесом -> установили перехватчик события, потом он выполняется на события...

Comment: one more example of problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229094/bug-javascript-or-cache-or-something-else